# Ввод в пустую переменную из input

Tags: python

Добавление значение из input в переменную "a"
Что необходимо сделать?

```
c = input('a: ')
a = ""
```

Comment: На выбор `a = input()` либо `c = input(); a = c` или `a += c`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

функция `input()` принимает (необязательный) параметр - строку, которая объясняет пользователю, что от него хочется задать, например

```
input('Задайте ваше имя: ')
```

выведет текст

> Задайте ваше имя:

и будет ждать, пока пользователь не введет что-то, окончено клавишем <kbd>Enter</kbd>, например

> Задайте ваше имя: Володя<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Теперь, как сохранить введенную строку, в нашем примере `'Володя'`? Надо вместо простого

```
input('Задайте ваше имя: ')
```

присвоить его какой-то переменной - вы хотите использовать переменную `a`, т.е. ваша команда будет

```
а = input('Задайте ваше имя: ')
```

Это всё - вторая команда в вашем вопросе (`a = ""`) бы только уничтожила только что принятую информацию `'Володя'`.

Да, вы теперь можете хотеть проверить, какое значение в переменной `a`, и так можете после команды  `input('Задайте ваше имя: ')` писать как следующую команду

```
print(a)
```

и получите соответственный вывод, в нашем примере

> ```
> Володя
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
import win32console 
win32console.PyConsoleScreenBufferType(win32console.GetStdHandle(\
    win32console.STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE))
# p = _
p.SetConsoleFont(8)
init(convert=True)


class GuessNumber:
    winner = False
    number = int

    def __init__(self):
        print(Style.BRIGHT + Fore.GREEN +"Угадай число от 0 до 20, у тебя три попытки")
        print("-------------------------------------------")
        self.game()

    def rnd(self):
        self.random_number = randrange(0, 20, 1)

    def check(self, num):
        self.number = num
        if self.number == self.random_number:
            self.winner = True
        else:
            return

    def game(self):
        count = 0
        self.rnd()
        while True:
            count += 1
            print(count, "попытка")
            user_number = int(input("Введите число:"))
            print("----------------------")
            self.check(user_number)
            if count == 3:
                print("К сожалению ты проиграл :(")
                print("Компьютер загадал число", self.random_number)
                input("Для выхода нажмите ENTER")
                break

            if self.number > self.random_number:
                print("Загаданое число меньше")
            elif self.number < self.random_number:
                print("Загаданое число больше")
            if self.winner:
                print("Ура ты победил!!!")
                print("Компьютер загадал число", self.random_number)
                input("Для выхода нажмите ENTER")
                break

def main():
    app = GuessNumber()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Обратный слеш для разрыва строки внутри скобок не нужен. Т.е. без обратного слеша будет работать.

Comment: Это для сайта при вставке кода)

Answer (score 0):

```python
a = []
while True:
     c = input('Как вас завут: ')
     b = input('\nПродолжить да & нет: ')
     a.append(c)
     if b == 'нет':
             break
     if b == 'да':
             print(c)
     else:
             print(c, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Хотелось бы отметить, что в питоне нет переменных, как таковых. Когда вы пишете код вроде:

```
>>> a = 5
```

Вы создаете ссылку  "a"  на объект 5. 
Также, в питоне нет "пустых" переменных.

```
>>> a = "" # Это создаст объект пустой строки.
>>> type(a)
<class 'str'>
```

Если вы пишете:

```
>>> x = 5  # Инициализация объекта 5
>>> y = "" # Инициализация объекта пустой строки
>>> y = x  # Создание дополнительной ссылки на объект 5
>>> y
5
```

Если вы хотите создать копию объекта, а не ссылку на него, воспользуйтесь модулем copy. За дополнительной информацией о модуле copy посмотрите: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html

Метод `input('Необязательное праглашение ввода:')` автоматически создает объект типа str. Но его можно преобразовать в int: `int(input('Необязательное праглашение ввода:'))`. И так как это обычный объект первого класса, его можно передавать в качестве аргумента без создание ссылки на него:

```
>>> for i in range(int(input('enter number of iterations: '))):
...     print(i)
... 
enter number of iterations: 5
0
1
2
3
4
>>>
```

Ссылку на объект нужно создавать в том случае, если этот объект используется в коде много раз. Ну или по ситуации.